# Agora with Flutter: Not able to call leavechannel for user when app crashed/hot-restarted/closed

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I successfully implemented a running mvp for a video call. The event handlers all work fine basically. Im recieving informations on when somebody joins or leaves the chat. But if I hot restart an emulator and or im closing the app/it gets interrupted, im not receiving any event anymore which results in that im not able to call `_eninge.leaveChannel();` which results in nobody can join anymore by getting the

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-17, request to join channel is rejected, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _MyAppState.initAgora (package:agorabloc/main.dart:99:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Error code 17 occurs when a user is already in the channel and you try to join the channel again. But im not able to call leave since im not receiving any events.. This is my code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'launch.dart';
import 'pages/index.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int? _remoteUid;
  late RtcEngine _engine;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }
  

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    // _users.clear();
    _engine.leaveChannel();
    _engine.destroy();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _addListeners(){
    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("local user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            
          });
        },
        rejoinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed) {
          print("remote user $uid rejoined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        leaveChannel: (stats) {
          setState(() {
            print('****** User left channel');
            _remoteUid = null;
          });
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          print("remote user $uid left channel");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = null;
            
          });
        },
        
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initAgora() async {
    // retrieve permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
print('init agora 1');
    //create the engine
    _engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(RtcEngineContext("xxx"));
    
    print('init agora 2');
    _addListeners();


print('init agora 3');


await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.enableAudio();
var rng = Random();
    final uId = rng.nextInt(100);
    await _engine.joinChannel('xxxxx', "firstchannel", null, uId);
    print('init agora 4');
  }

  // Create UI with local view and remote view
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _remoteVideo(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: const Center(
                child: RtcLocalView.SurfaceView(
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(onPressed: () async {
            await _engine.leaveChannel();
            setState(() {
            _remoteUid = null;
          });
          } , child: Text('Leave'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    if (_remoteUid != null) {
     return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: _remoteUid!, channelId: 'firstchannel');
    } else {
      return Text(
        'Please wait for remote user to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
    
  }
}
```

I need to detect if the app is crashed,closed,interrupted so I can call `leaveChannel()`. Using `WidgetBindingObservers` doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I encountered this in the past. You need to release the `RtcEngine` in `dispose()`

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  /* Other dispose logic */

  // Releases hardware resources
  // and should allow reconnection
  // with hot reload/restart
  _engine.release();

  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes, this needs to be integrated in bloc pattern in my case somehow, but im not sure how. there is also the ability to create a dispose but it seems not working properly